# Can a gas molecule theoretically have zero velocity?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, stochastic-processes

According to Maxwell's speed distribution law gas molecule can have speed which lies between zero to infinity. But in the graph of the distribution curve it seems to touch zero velocity. So can a gas particle practically have exactly zero velocity or is that just in theoretic sense?

Comment: The probability that a random variable with a density takes a particular value is always $0$. This is thus in particular the case here. (Of course, if the question is whether microstates in which there is a particle with $0$ velocity are allowed, the answer is obviously yes. They just have probability $0$ of occurring.)

Comment: @YvanVelenik it should probably be added, in case that the OP isn't familiar with probability theory in detail, that an event with 0 probability can still occur.

Comment: Take any particle in the gas, perform a boost so that it is at rest in the frame.

Answer (score 2):

There are several way to look at why the answer is effectively "no". The Botlzman factor is the probability $P$ of a degree of freedom having energy $E$ at temperature $T$:

$$ P(E) \propto e^{-E/kT}$$

which, for an ideal gas atom with mass $m$ moving in the $x$-direction is:

$$  P(E_x) \propto e^{-mv_x^2/2kT} $$

which is finite as $v_x \rightarrow 0$, where $v_x$ is the velocity in the $x$-direction, with $-\infty<v_x<+\infty$.

The problem is that $v_x=0$ is not enough. For $$||\vec v||=0$$ we must also have $v_y=v_z=0$, and that is clearly much less probable.

As pointed out in the comments, one must consider an infinitesimal region $dv_x$ to get a non zero result, so the combination of $x$, $y$, and $z$ looks like:

$$P(\vec v)d^3v \propto e^{-mv_x^2/2kT}e^{-mv_y^2/2kT}e^{-mv_z^2/2kT}=e^{-mv^2/2kT}d^3v$$

where the Boltzman factor is again finite at $||v||=0$. The problem is $d^3v$, which when converted into a speed via spherical coordinates is:

$$d^3v \rightarrow v^2 dv$$

and is interpreted as the differential volume of a shell extending from $v$ to $v+dv$. This given the final form of the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution:

$$P(v) \propto v^2 e^{-mv^2/2kT}$$

which is zero at $v=0$ because  there is no volume in phase space there.

Comment: This is nothing more than the statement that (classical) velocity is a continuous quantity, so any specific value of $\vec{v}$ has zero probability.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at the problem is that since velocity is dependent on temperature, to have a zero velocity molecule, it becomes essential to achieve absolute zero temperature which is not possible. So, it is not possible to have zero velocity in Maxwellian distribution.